# Is there any precedent for the UK arresting a diplomat on their own soil?

Tags: united-kingdom, international-relations, wikileaks

As Assange gets citizenship to Ecuador and becomes an official diplomat of the country, I'm wondering if there is any precedent for the UK to arrest him in that capacity for alleged transgressions that took place prior to assuming the post?

Comment: He is not an "official diplomat" unless HMG accepts him as such,

Comment: The actions after [the killing of Yvonne Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Yvonne_Fletcher) came close, but no one was actually arrested, and it wouldn’t have been for acts prior to assuming the post.

Comment: See also R v Pinochet

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If the UK had accepted [Ecuador's request to make Mr Assange an officially accredited diplomat](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/12/ecuador_tried_to_make_julian_assange_a_diplomat/), he would been immediately entitled to protection under the [Vienna Convention](http://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf), to which the UK is a [ratified signatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parties_to_the_Vienna_Convention_on_the_Law_of_Treaties). Specifically he would have enjoyed Article 29 which explicitly forbids the arrest of a diplomat.

> *The person of a diplomatic agent shall be inviolable. He shall not be
>   liable to any form of arrest or detention. The receiving State shall
>   treat him with due respect and shall take all appropriate steps to
>   prevent any attack on his person, freedom or dignity.*

This is also considered a part of UK law, in relation to the [Diplomatic Privileges Act 1964](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1964/81/section/2), specifically article 2.5;

> *Articles 35, 36 and 40 shall be construed as **granting any privilege or
>   immunity which they*** [The Vienna Convention] ***require to be granted.***

Given his chequered past, it's likely that the Ecuadorians *envisaged* that the UK would accept their proposal (allowing him to leave their embassy unhindered), then immediately exercise their rights under Article 9 of the Vienna Convention to declare him *persona non grata* and ask him to leave the country.

> *The receiving State may at any time and without having to explain its
>   decision, notify the sending State that the head of the mission or any
>   member of the diplomatic staff of the mission is persona non grata or
>   that any other member of the staff of the mission is not acceptable.
>   In any such case, the sending State shall, as appropriate, either
>   recall the person concerned or terminate his functions with the
>   mission.*

Instead, the UK exercised its rights (under the same article) and simply declared his appointment not acceptable.

---

As to whether the *pre-planned* arrest of an accredited diplomat has occurred on British soil, the answer is that such a thing hasn't occurred for several hundred years. The last case appears to have been in 1717 with the arrest of [Karl (or Carl) Gyllenborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Gyllenborg), the Swedish Ambassador. His papers and person were seized when it became clear that he was part of a conspiracy against the Crown and he was imprisoned for five months before he was permitted to leave the country.

[image]

Comment: So does the Vienna convention state the receiving country has to *accept* the status?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - No. Absolutely not. Article 9 says **"*A person may be declared non grata or not acceptable before arriving in the territory of
the receiving State.*"**. An appointment needs to be *accepted*.

Comment: Could you integrate that into your answer. I don't think it's explicit that the UK is breaking the Vienna convention here, and it was very much apart of my curiosity in asking the question. The case of them arresting a diplomat was also prior to the vienna convention

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I've edited to explain on what basis they refused his appointment.

Comment: As I read the answer for the first time; I understood it in following way (especially the first sentence): UK needs to “accept” - like sign some kind of pamphlet first...; 2nd language here, so the “Had the UK” thing may be the confusing part I am not sure. Comment section clarified it.

Comment: @Kyslik - Yes. The would-be diplomat's credentials are presented to the Foreign Office who need to sign them and return them. At that point the person is a diplomat. No signature = no appointment = no immunity.

Comment: Nice answer. Although article 9 presents some difficulties, as Assange already is in UK territory; contrary to popular belief ambassies are not foreign soil, just inviolable -host country forces cannot enter without being allowed by the ambassador-. I wonder if someone would try to pull something due to this (but I would not count on it working).

Comment: @SJuan76 - This is addressed in the Diplomatic Privileges Act 1964; "*Every person entitled to privileges and immunities shall enjoy them from the moment he enters the territory of the receiving State on proceeding to take up his post or, **if already in its territory, from the moment when his appointment is notified to the Ministry for Foreign Affairs or such other ministry as may be agreed.***" - So he can be appointed a diplomat *while still in residence in the UK* (assuming the Foreign Office accepts his credentials. Which they didn't).

Comment: An interesting side discussion would be about why the UK did not accept Assange's appointment. Anyone brave enough?

Comment: Whay if he would be appointed a diplomat to another country? Would the UK honor it?

Comment: @Anixx - That seems doubtful.

Comment: @Sentinel: The UK government perhaps takes the view that Assange has not genuinely switched careers and does not genuinely aspire to enter diplomatic service in the UK. Assange's main aims in life do not seem to be  facilitating good relations between Ecuador and the UK.

Comment: @Anixx: An Assistant Attaché to the Ecuadorian embassy in Japan doesn't have any special diplomatic privileges outside Japan. Neither would Assange.

Comment: @EvanCarroll "I don't think it's explicit that the UK is breaking the Vienna convention here" It's explicit that the UK is _not_ breaking the Vienna convention!

Comment: This is true if Ecuador tries to make Assange a diplomat in its UK embassy. But if it appoints him as Ecuador’s UN representative, he may not be arrested by any UN member state while travelling to or from a UN session, and the UK can’t reject the appointment (although the UN probably could).

Comment: @MikeScott - That's worthy of asking as a new question. For the record, that ain't gonna work either - His immunity would only apply for as long as he's in transit to New York and let's ask ourselves, **where's the very last place he'd want to be when his immunity runs out?**

Comment: @Valorum It’s to _or from_ the meeting. His immunity lasts until he gets back to Ecuador after the session. But it might be prudent for him to travel on a private jet and change the flight plan after leaving UK airspace.

Comment: @MikeScott - As soon as he's over international airspace, I'd imagine that he'd find his plane had a friendly escort.

Answer (score 26):

According to the [Crown Prosecution Service's guidance on diplomatic immunity](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/diplomatic-immunity-and-diplomatic-premises) (emphasis mine):

> Diplomatic immunity in the UK is conferred on all entitled members of a foreign mission (and entitled family members forming part of their household, provided they are not nationals of the UK) who have been notified to, **and accepted by**, the Foreign and Commonwealth Office (FCO) as performing a diplomatic function.

In other words, once the diplomatic status of an individual is accepted by the FCO, the diplomat can only be arrested with the permission of the sending state.  Normally, this recognition of diplomatic status happens almost immediately when a diplomat enters the country using their diplomatic passport.

As has been reported by various media (such as the [London Evening Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/julian-assanges-bid-for-diplomatic-status-is-refused-by-britain-a3737216.html)), the FCO has refused Ecuador's request to recognise Mr. Assange's status as a diplomat, primarily because of the charges already outstanding against him.  Because the FCO does not see him as an official diplomat, then he is subject to arrest and prosecution as any other foreign citizen.

Comment: "Normally, this recognition of diplomatic status happens almost immediately when a diplomat enters the country using their diplomatic passport." - Doesn't it happen *before* the diplomat enters the country?

Comment: No, because it can't officially happen until they enter the country. But it's generally agreed upon well beforehand, specifically to avoid situations like this.

Comment: @Shadur it absolutely can happen before they enter the country. See article 4: "The sending State must make certain that the agrément of the receiving State has been given for
the person it proposes to accredit as head of the mission to that State."  The receiving state must accept the diplomat before the diplomat can be appointed.  The diplomat enjoys immunity from the moment of arrival in the receiving state, before the presentation of credentials (article 39).

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica you are correct.  The receiving state must indicate that it intends to accept the diplomat before the diplomat is accredited, and diplomatic immunity begins immediately when the diplomat arrives, not "almost immediately."